# Extract specific words using regex or substring from a column in R

Tags: r, regex, text, substr

I have the below data:

```
    Opex_Spend_Month    Opex_Spend_YTD  Major_Category  NBS_Region  Sub_Category
92179.84            113542.84       Contingent Labour   EUROPE  TEMP:OTH.CONT.WORKER
297.82              82392.82        Contingent Labour   EUROPE  TEMP:OTH.CONT.WORKER
13974.8             34917.8         Contingent Labour   EUROPE  TEMP:OTH.CONT.WORKER
138.6               63125.6         Contingent Labour   EUROPE  TEMP:OTH.CONT.WORKER
NA                  73097           Contingent Labour   EUROPE  TEMP:MSP NON IT
NA                  96035           Contingent Labour   EUROPE  TEMP:MSP NON IT
1388.65             68934.65        Contingent Labour   EUROPE  TEMP:MSP NON IT
5393.76             18748.76        Contingent Labour   EUROPE  TEMP:MSP IT
528.38              82195.38        Contingent Labour   EUROPE  TEMP:MSP IT
22369               95468           Contingent Labour   EUROPE  TEMP:MSP IT
```

From the column Sub_Category I want to be able to select the last parts of Cont Worker, Non IT & IT and I am not sure what regex or substring function to use.

**Desired Output**

```
Opex_Spend_Month    Opex_Spend_YTD  Major_Category  NBS_Region  Sub_Category            Category
92179.84            113542.84       Contingent Labour   EUROPE  TEMP:OTH.CONT.WORKER    Cont Worker
297.82              82392.82        Contingent Labour   EUROPE  TEMP:OTH.CONT.WORKER    Cont Worker
13974.8             34917.8         Contingent Labour   EUROPE  TEMP:OTH.CONT.WORKER    Cont Worker
138.6               63125.6         Contingent Labour   EUROPE  TEMP:OTH.CONT.WORKER    Cont Worker
NA                  73097           Contingent Labour   EUROPE  TEMP:MSP NON IT         Non IT
NA                  96035           Contingent Labour   EUROPE  TEMP:MSP NON IT         Non IT
1388.65             68934.65        Contingent Labour   EUROPE  TEMP:MSP NON IT         Non IT
5393.76             18748.76        Contingent Labour   EUROPE  TEMP:MSP IT             IT
528.38              82195.38        Contingent Labour   EUROPE  TEMP:MSP IT             IT
22369               95468           Contingent Labour   EUROPE  TEMP:MSP IT             IT
```

Can someone please help me with this??

Comment: What's the pattern? How can you tell `NON IT` and `IT` apart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can do:

 gsub(".*?(\\.|\\s)(\\w+)","\\2 ",dat$Sub_Category)
```

Here is an example: Will just call the last two columns(5:6) for you to see what happens:

```
transform(dat,category=gsub(".*?(\\.|\\s)(\\w+)","\\2 ",Sub_Category))[5:6]
           Sub_Category     category
1  TEMP:OTH.CONT.WORKER CONT WORKER 
2  TEMP:OTH.CONT.WORKER CONT WORKER 
3  TEMP:OTH.CONT.WORKER CONT WORKER 
4  TEMP:OTH.CONT.WORKER CONT WORKER 
5       TEMP:MSP NON IT      NON IT 
6       TEMP:MSP NON IT      NON IT 
7       TEMP:MSP NON IT      NON IT 
8           TEMP:MSP IT          IT 
9           TEMP:MSP IT          IT 
10          TEMP:MSP IT          IT
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(df1$Sub_Category, "(CONT\\.WORKER|NON IT|IT)$")
```

Comment: My initial thought but this overfits the example

Comment: @Sotos It is extracting those substrings after running the example.  I am not sure about the formatting, if it needs to be changed

Comment: Oh, yes I know. I am not blaming/attacking you, I am trying to say that OP is unclear about the pattern

Comment: You are right.  The description and the expected output is a bit different

Answer (score 0):

In Base R:

```
df$Category = trimws(gsub('([A-Z]+:[A-Z]+|\\.)', ' ', df$Sub_Category))
```